# Interpolating between curves in spherical coordinates, preserving a slope

Tags: matlab

I have two curves, at 0 and 90 deg (azimuth), descrived by points:

```
aa =

   1.0e+03 *

    1.1534    1.1534
    1.1279    1.1528
    1.0836    1.1523
    1.0194    1.1519
    0.9345    1.1523
    0.8357    1.1519
    0.7138    1.1515
    0.5865    1.1498
    0.4662    1.1458
    0.3426    1.1401
    0.2390    1.1296
    0.1573    1.1146
    0.1061    1.0938
    0.0829    1.0649
    0.0695    1.0263
    0.0589    0.9613
    0.0524    0.8576
    0.0480    0.7146
    0.0454    0.5518
    0.0435    0.3889
    0.0415    0.2570
    0.0399    0.1599
    0.0380    0.1010
    0.0360    0.0725
    0.0337    0.0568
    0.0310    0.0478
    0.0280    0.0408
    0.0248    0.0341
    0.0215    0.0273
    0.0178    0.0217
    0.0166    0.0173
    0.0159    0.0126
    0.0112    0.0081
    0.0070    0.0034
    0.0039    0.0013
    0.0009    0.0003
         0         0
```

so,

```
theta = deg2rad(0:2.5:90);
phi =  deg2rad([0 90]);
```

I need to interpolate between these curves, or to obtain curves in steps of 5 degrees

```
phi2 =  deg2rad(0:5:90);
```

Thee thing is that I need to preserve the slope, I've tried:

```
New_curves = interp1(phi, aa',phi2, 'pchip');
```

But the resulting curves are non-monotonic (I would include an image but I'm new here and so I'm not allowed).
Coould you perhaps help me out, please? How can I do the interpolation so that the curves are monotonic (the slope is preserved?). I tired to convert to cartesian and interpolate there, but that didn't work very well either.

Comment: Your question is unclear, is `aa` in spherical, polar or cartesian coordinates ? If your coordinates are spherical where is the rho parameter ?

Comment: Thanks. Yes, aa is in spherical coordinates, theta is the polar and phi is the azimuth.